# Xamarin.FormsMap - if I can use xamarin maps for commercial project

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My current project shows points on a map and has two type of users:

- Customer user who will order items, e.g food.
- Provider User who will provide the items to the user, e.g. a restaurant

The Provider User will pay to be shown on the map.

Can I use Xamarin.forms for this app?
And will I need to pay for using maps to Google/Apple?

Answer (score 2):

As Jason said you don't need to pay to use the Map APIs for both platforms(iOS/Android).

There are some services that you need to pay (Google Places API for iOS/Android) for have a look here at the [google site](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/) but it depends what you are going to do in the app but if it is just to display points you should be fine with the Maps API.

Also you can use Xamarin.Forms for this have a look at the Xamarin tutorial on the map control [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no license fee or restriction on commercial use for using Maps in your App.  Note that Google requires you to register and use a Map API key to use their maps; Apple does not.